# How can I find an object with fabricjs

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have circles on my webpage, and I want to find a circle and then draw a line to another circle.

Is this possible with FabricJS?

Comment: Have you tried? Please post your code here.

Comment: No, actually I just have started, and I didn't find anything about find elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try starting here:

http://fabricjs.com/stickman/

http://fabricjs.com/quadratic-curve/

I made a example for you:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.add(
    new fabric.Circle({ top: 50, left: 50, radius: 25, fill: 'red' }),
    new fabric.Circle({ top: 300, left: 300, radius: 25, fill: 'red' })
);
canvas.renderAll();


$('#drawLine').click(function(){
 canvas.add(new fabric.Line([50, 50, 300, 300], {
        left: 50+25, //25 = 50/radius
        top: 50+25,
        stroke: 'blue'
    }));
});
```

Link here: http://jsfiddle.net/q6Y6k/17/

Comment: Thank you I'll start with that!